# Second async operation started...don't see how

Tags: entity-framework, async-await, asp.net-web-api2

I'm getting the error about a second async operation starting on the context before the previous async operation ended, but I'm not seeing where it's happening.  This is the code I'm using.  Each of the async calls are using await, so what am I doing wrong?

This is a method on a Web API 2 call.

```cs
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SendAssessmentArsAsync(int assessmentId) {
    using (var context = new LAMPEntities()) {
        var assessment = await context.EHS_Assessment_Audit.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.id == assessmentId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        var arsQuery = from r in context.EHS_Assessment_Audit_AR.AsNoTracking()
                       where r.EHS_Assessment_Audit_Id == assessmentId
                       join w in context.Worker on r.Assignee_WWID equals w.WWID
                       select new {
                           w.Email,
                           w.Full_Name,
                           r.AR,
                           r.Due_Date
                       };

        var ars = await arsQuery.ToArrayAsync();

        var lab = from s in context.Lab_Space.AsNoTracking()
                  where s.id == assessment.Lab_Space.id
                  join w in context.Worker.AsNoTracking() on s.Contact_WWID equals w.WWID
                  where w.Email != null
                  join d_join in context.Worker.AsNoTracking() on s.Delegate equals d_join.WWID into d_grp
                  from d in d_grp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  select new {
                      Owner = w.Email,
                      Delegate = d.Email,
                      Barcode = s.Entry_Bar_Code,
                      Label = s.Floor_Space_Label,
                      Id = s.id
                  };

        var mails = await lab.FirstAsync();
```

When it hits that last line is where it is throwing the exception.

Exception message:

> A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Here's the exception as shown via the webservice call:

```
b__a()
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.d__3d`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.d__9`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.d__e.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
 at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyAsyncEnumerator`1.d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerableExtensions.d__1d`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
 at LabSORService.Controllers.EHSController.d__21.MoveNext() in ...\\Controllers\\EHSController.cs:line 854
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.d__1`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__15.MoveNext()" }
{
  "message": "An error has occurred.",
  "exceptionMessage": "A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.",
  "exceptionType": "System.NotSupportedException",
  "stackTrace": "   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.QueryParameterExpression.TryGetFieldOrPropertyValue(MemberExpression me, Object instance, Object& memberValue)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.QueryParameterExpression.TryEvaluatePath(Expression expression, ConstantExpression& constantExpression)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.QueryParameterExpression.EvaluateParameter(Object[] arguments)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClassc.
```

Comment: Did you try to use the same context from different threads?

Comment: No.  It's just a web api method that gets called from an HTTP request (I added that to the question)

Comment: Where does that action get the context from? Where is the context created? You should add the relevant code *and* the relevant tags. ASP.NET Web API Full or Core? Is the context injected, perhaps as a singleton? You should post the full exception too, including its call stack. You can get that easily with Exception.ToString().

Comment: It's web api 2...tag added.  I also show the method and context now, sorry.

Comment: The exception's call stack shows where the exception occured and the calls that led to this point. The code posted here shouldn't through, although it can be simplified immensely. The callstack could provide a hint about what happened. The *full* exception text, returned by `Exception.ToString()`, contains the message, any inner exceptions and the full call stack.

Comment: As for simplifying this, it's *EF*'s job to generate JOINs from the relations and navigation properties between entities. `Worker` should have an `Assesments` and a `Delegate` property. `Lab_Space` should have a `Workers` property, etc. You could write eg `from worker in context.Workers where worker.LabSpace.ID=someID select new {worker.Email,worker.Delegate.Email,worker.LabSpace.Entry_Bar_Code...}`

Comment: I'd love to do that, but `Lab_Space` has more than one reference to a `Worker` and SQL server doesn't seem to allow me to do that.  It'll let me make one a foreign key to the `Worker` table but not two.  That's why I'm manually doing the JOIN.  I pasted the exception text.  The line 854 it refers to is the last one of the code shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely

```
where s.id == assessment.Lab_Space.id
```

is triggering lazy loading of `Lab_Space` navigation property in inappropriate time.

Assuming you have no explicit FK property like `Lab_Space_Id` (if you do have, just use it instead of `Lab_Space.id`), either eager load it (preferable):

```
var assessment = await context.EHS_Assessment_Audit.AsNoTracking()
    .Include(x => x.Lab_Space) // <--
    .Where(x => x.id == assessmentId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

or evaluate it outside the query:

```
var labSpaceId = assessment.Lab_Space.id; // <--
var lab = from s in context.Lab_Space.AsNoTracking()
          where s.id == labSpaceId // <--
          ...
```

Note that in the original query, `assessment.Lab_Space` access is just *recorded* in the query expression tree. The actual evaluation (hence triggering the lazy load) happens as part of the execution of the query.

Comment: Thank you so much.  Changing to the foreign key, which I don't know why I wasn't already using, fixed the problem.